# Longest Substring in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

This is my function for determining the Longest Substring between two strings in Java.

```
public class Main {
    public static String longestSubstring(String str1, String str2){
        int row = str1.length();
        int col = str2.length();

        int[][] checker = new int[row][col];

        int max = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < col; j++){
                if(str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)){
                    if((i -1 > 0) && (j -1 >0)){
                        checker[i][j] = checker[i-1][j-1] +1;

                    }else{
                        checker[i][j]++;
                    }
                    max = checker[i][j];
                    r = i;
                    c = j;

                }else continue;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(true){
            if(checker[r][c] == 0) break;
            sb.append(str1.charAt(r));
            r--;
            c--;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        String str1 = "adedfrgyu";
        String str2 = "arvbfrgykset";

       String str3 = "aaaaaaatyuieo";
       String str4 = "aaaaaklui";

        System.out.println(longestSubstring(str1, str2));
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but wondering is the algorithm is correct. It passes all the test cases that I could make up.

Comment: Suggestion: use a random word generator for the test cases.

Comment: If you want to make sure that all cases are covered by your tests (good testing requires such) then you need a tool that generate coverage data. You run your tests, then check coverage. If a case is never hit (i.e. an if() or else block never entered) then you've got a problem in your tests.

Comment: Surely you could have come up with more test cases and discovered that your code doesn't work.

Comment: (I think I'd like _Longest Common Substring_ much better as a title, with _in Java_ optional _if_ the first tag is `java`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I liked your DP approach and use of stringbuider instead of string.

1. But, the code gives null pointer exception :

   ```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
   at Test.longestSubstring(Test.java:157)
   at Test.main(Test.java:22)
   ```

for the input `System.out.println(longestSubstring("aabb", "akk"));`

The reason is that whenever the resultant substring starts from index 0, this code will throw a null pointer exception because  `checker[0][0]` is 1(instead of 0), if the first characters match. Because, you're using `if(checker[r][c] == 0) break;` as the criteria to end the while loop. One solution is to have the while loop run for `max` number of times. Other approach is to use an array of 1 greater size i.e. `int[][] checker = new int[row+1][col+1];`

2. Moreover, there is a small bug in this code :-

For input `System.out.println(longestSubstring("aabb", "abbbb"));`, the output is "bb". But, the right answer is "abb". Even for the given test cases,

```
  String str3 = "aaaaaaatyuieo";
   String str4 = "aaaaaklui";

    System.out.println(longestSubstring(str1, str2));
```

The answer should be "aaaaa". But, it returns "ui". The reason for that is that you should check if checker[i][j] is greater than max before assigning

```
max = checker[i][j];
r = i;
c = j;
```

3. You need not write `else continue;` as the last statement in the loop.

Here is the complete code:-

```
    public static String longestSubstring(String str1, String str2){
    int row = str1.length();
    int col = str2.length();

    int[][] checker = new int[row+1][col+1];

    int max = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            if(str1.charAt(i-1) == str2.charAt(j-1)){
                checker[i][j] = checker[i-1][j-1] +1;
                if(checker[i][j] > max){
                    max = checker[i][j];
                    r = i;
                    c = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(true){
        if(checker[r][c] == 0) break;
        sb.append(str1.charAt(r-1));
        r--;
        c--;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Please check your comment in 2. IMHO for input of "aabb" and "abbbb" the answer should be "abb", not "aab".